# difference between text_iarchive and binary_iarchive

Tags: boost

Is there any performance advantage using binary_iarchive over text_iarchive? I only know that binary_iarchive is non portable and text_iarchive is portable. I am looking for serialization library by which i can write stl::map directly to file and read it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write a test case and profile it? However I would assume binary is faster since for example a 32 bit `int` as text could take up 10 bytes (80 bits) but in binary it will be 4 bytes. On the other hand this means that if most of your values are under 999 (in base 10) it might be faster to use text. Anyhow run some typical data sets and profile and see what works best for you.

Then for example `boost::serialization` will add some overhead to keep track of what is written and if it needs to handle pointers.

However file I/O is usually very slow so it stands to reason that you would want to read as few bytes as possible from a file if performance is a concern for you.

On the other hand if you read the file once in a program, i.e. slow file I/O wont affect the over all performance I would go with portability. But do remember that a there is no guarantee that numbers can be be ported from a 64 bit program to a 32 bit program safely. If the 64 bit system has 64 bit `int`s and the 32 bit system has 32 bit `int`s there might be trouble even if a text archive is used.

Answer (score 0):

Text archive would be somewhat bigger than the binary one. If the portability is your primary concern -- consider using the [portale binary archive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/todo.html#portablebinaryarchives).